# Bind Usercontrol Property to a Button ContextMenu in a Datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datagrid, user-controls

Good day.
I have a ContextMenu in a Datagrid in my UserControl which i'm trying to bind to my UserControl Property based on the UserControl Name, but the binding is not working.

UserControl Name

```
 x:Name="usercontrolManageTransferCash"
```

UserControl Property

```
public bool CanDelete
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(CanDeleteProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CanDeleteProperty, value); }
    }

public static readonly DependencyProperty CanDeleteProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("CanDelete", typeof(bool), typeof(ManageTransferCash), new PropertyMetadata(false));
```

My Binding CanDelete in the ContextMenu to my UserControl Name

```
<DataGrid x:Name="DG_TransferDepositHis" SelectionMode="Single" 
          VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,0,0,0"  FontSize="14"  >
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Visibility="Collapsed" Header="ID" Binding="{Binding TransferHistoryId}" Width="auto"/>                           
        <DataGridTextColumn  Header="Date" Binding="{Binding Date, Converter={StaticResource ShortDateFormatConverter}}" MinWidth="100" Width="auto"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn  Header="Timeago" Binding="{Binding TimeAgo, Converter={StaticResource TimeAgoValueConverter}}"  Width="*"/>


        <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="auto" >
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <!--<TextBlock Text="Manage"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="50,0" />-->
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="1,0" >
                        <Button x:Name="btn_action" Content="Action" FontSize="11" Margin="3,0,3,0" 
                                Style="{DynamicResource btn-primary}" Width="65" Click="btn_action_Click"  >
                            <Button.ContextMenu>
                                <ContextMenu x:Name="bank_history_dropdown_menu" 
                                             Style="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignContextMenu}" >                                                        
                                    <MenuItem   IsEnabled="{Binding CanDelete, ElementName=usercontrolManageTransferCash}"
                                        Name="menuItem_clear"  Header="Clear"   Height="36"  Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignMenuItem}" Click="menuItem_clear_Click" />                                                        
                                </ContextMenu>
                            </Button.ContextMenu>

                        </Button>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Please i need help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `ElementName` to bind to the parent `UserControl` because the `ContextMenu` resides in a different element tree.

You should be able to bind the `Tag` property of the `Button` to the parent `UserControl` and then bind to it through the `PlacementTarget` of the `ContextMenu` though. Try this:

```
<Button x:Name="btn_action" Content="Action" FontSize="11" Margin="3,0,3,0" 
                Style="{DynamicResource btn-primary}" Width="65" Click="btn_action_Click"
                Tag="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}">
    <Button.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu x:Name="bank_history_dropdown_menu" Style="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignContextMenu}" >
            <MenuItem  IsEnabled="{Binding PlacementTarget.Tag.DataContext.CanDelete, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContextMenu}}"
                       Name="menuItem_clear" Header="Clear" Height="36" Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignMenuItem}" Click="menuItem_clear_Click" />
        </ContextMenu>
    </Button.ContextMenu>
</Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try binding to your `UserConrole` `CanDelete` property by using RelativeSource expression for example like this:

```
IsEnabled={Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type YourNamespace.YourUserControleType}}, Path=CanDelete}
```

this kind of binding will search for element of type 'YourUserControlType' type up in XAML tree and first element it finds it'll grab its CanDelete property and bind to it.

Comment: Did not work, did what you wrote..   `IsEnabled="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ui:ManageTransferCash}}, Path=CanDelete}"`